# How do I use a free body diagram in this case?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces, free-body-diagram

[image]

In the above cases I want to find the acceleration $a$ for $m_1$. I can do it by considering $m_1$ and $m_2$ to be a system, which would give me $a = F/(m_1+m_2)$. How can I use a free-body diagram instead to calculate the acceleration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I can do it by considering $m_1$ and $m_2$ to be a system, which would give me $a=F/(m_1+m_2)$. How can I use a free-body diagram instead to calculate the acceleration?

But this *is* by the use of a free-body diagram. Otherwise, how would you know that it is the force $F$ you should include?

Because, your acceleration expression comes from Newton's 2nd law:

$$\sum F=ma$$

where $\sum F$ is **the sum of all forces in that particular direction**. Drawing you free-body force diagram will then show that there is *only* the force $F$ in the horizontal direction, so the formula becomes:

$$\sum F=ma \quad\Leftrightarrow\quad F=ma \quad\Leftrightarrow\quad 
F=(m_1+m_2)a \quad\Leftrightarrow\quad
a=\frac{F}{m_1+m_2}$$

---

As far as I can see, the full free-body force diagram for both masses as one object will show the force $F$ horizontally and weight $w$ and normal force $n$ vertically.

*I here assume no friction on the ground. Also, I assume both these masses to stick together. If this is not the case, please make that clear. Also, I'm not sure what the difference between the two pictures is showing.*

Comment: I'm sorry if the question wasn't very clear, but if I wanted to find the acceleration for $m_1$, how would I do so by only making the free body diagram for $m_1$? Also, no, in the second diagram the two bodies don't stick together. All surfaces are frictionless

Comment: @xasthor If all surfaces are frictionless, then you can consider m1 for itself. The free body diagram for m1 will have F horizontally and weight, normal force and the weight of m2 vertically. Put up newton's second law in the horizontal direction and you still only have F, so the equation is $F=am_1$.

Comment: Alright, and how would I make the free body diagram for $m_1$ in the first diagram?

Comment: If the first diagram shows the boxes stuck to each other, then there is a horizontal friction force as well. You do not have to consider that though, since this can be seen as one whole system as described in the answer

Comment: If you *do want* to consider the m1 box alone, then you can still make the free-body diagram with the extra horizontal friction force. But since this friction force is unknown you need one more equation. So in this case, you must make a free body diagram on m2 as well, where this friction is also present (but in the opposite direction). Setting up Newton's second law for each of them gives two equations with this friction force and acceleration as the unknowns, and then it can be solved.

Comment: Recently another question arose in my mind.  What if in the first diagram, $m_2$ was suspended to the pole on $m_1$ by a string? How would I calculate the net force on $m_1$ and its acceleration?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/39109/discussion-between-xasthor-and-steeven).

Answer (score 2):

You will need to use two free body diagrams, one for each mass, one FBD will include the force of A on B and the other one the force of B on A. Both mass have the same acceleration (do they), so you end up with a little system of three equations and three unknowns.

Comment: Yeah,but I'm having problems making a free-body diagram. $m_2$ seems to act only in the vertical direction so through a free-body diagram I'm unable to see how it affects acceleration $a$ in the horizontal

Comment: There'll be a pair of frictional forces between the blocks too.

Comment: I'm assuming the surfaces to be frictionless